# No suitable constructor found while parsing a subclass in Jackson/Jerkson (Scala)?

Tags: java, scala, jackson

I am trying to parse a class and for some reason Jackson (actually Jerkson interface in Scala) is taking a dump. I am guessing it might have something to do with `BoardOpen` being a subclass of a `MessageEvent` class:

```
class BoardOpen(

  override val channel: String

) extends MessageEvent(channel)
```

and

```
class MessageEvent( val channel: String = "/" )
```

The full error:

```
The error com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException: No suitable constructor found
for type [simple type, class engine.event.BoardOpen]: can not instantiate from J
SON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4004c5b3; line: 1, column: 2]
        at com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException$.apply(ParsingException.scala:17)
        at com.codahale.jerkson.Parser$class.parse(Parser.scala:86)
        at com.codahale.jerkson.Json$.parse(Json.scala:6)
        at com.codahale.jerkson.Parser$class.parse(Parser.scala:14)
        at com.codahale.jerkson.Json$.parse(Json.scala:6)
        at controllers.socket.MessageParser$.matchMsg(MessageParser.scala:59)
        at controllers.socket.MessageParser$.parseRawMessage(MessageParser.scala:90)
        at controllers.socket.MessageParser$.readStringMsg(MessageParser.scala:42)
```

And here's what's going on when I go to parse the data:

```
msgCase match {
       case "BoardOpen"            => parse[BoardOpen](msgData)
```

and the JSON looks like:

```
{"channel":"/board"}
```

Any ideas why it is failing? Thanks.

**Update:**

Because there's only the `channel` property to worry about, I thought I'd see what would happen if I changed parsing to `parse[MessageEvent](msgData)` and strangely it spit the same error:

```
The error com.codahale.jerkson.ParsingException: No suitable constructor found
for type [simple type, class com.alloyengine.powder.MessageEvent]: can not insta
ntiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@34fd2520; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing with MessageEvent as a trait instead of as a class? The channel arg wouldn't be marked 'override' then.

Comment: Actually, yes. What I did was transformed each MessageEvent subclass into a case class and left MessageEvent as a trait. It fixes the problem, but doesn't exactly tell me why. I do know this is realated to case classes being introduced...